# Safe to travel to Yerevan with my wife

Tags: germany, armenia, yerevan

I would like to make a 7-day trip with my wife from Germany to Yerevan, the Armenian capital.  Despite lots of useful information on the Web about the city I still have some doubts regarding safety on the streets at day/early night; therefore I would like to get some advice: are there any security issues I should take into account while walking with my wife on the street at day/early night in Yerevan?

Comment: I would definitely not recommend it if you happen to be of Turkish descent.

Comment: That is a good point, thankfully I am not neither is my wife, I am Mexican of Spanish descent and she is German.

Comment: I visited Armenia a few years ago and thought it an extremely welcoming country.

Comment: @alamar is that recommendation based on some knowledge you have about problems encountered by people of Turkish descent in Yerevan, or on an assumption?

Comment: @phoog an assumption.  As @Jan said `There are things I would try doing and there are the *others*.`

Comment: @alamar My understanding is that Turks are generally received well in Armenia as long as they are careful to be respectful of the sensitive political issue.  It's not hard to find stories online reflecting this.

Answer (score 5):

Traveled there several times (German, living in Ukraine) and security was never an issue. Border guards at airport are unfriendly in Soviet/Russian way, that's all. Usually taxi drivers at arrival will try to rip you off with fares - anyway, nothing different than Tbilisi or Kyiv. I waited till the last taxi arrived and after all, I was offered a ride twice cheaper than at the beginning ;-). May recommend the factory tours in the Yerevan wine factory and the Ararat cognac factory. Also the Garni archaeological site ,Chor Virap or Noravankh church in the south (depends how much time you plan to spend), also to drive with the Tatev cable car or to make wine degustations in Areni. Concerning culture, their National History museum and the national gallery are marvelous.
Political matters like "friendship with Russia", hostility to Turkey or Azerbaijan I would rather avoid. It's a very emotional factor for them, which I didn't want to touch (like f.e.also Macedonia for Greek).